# How to eliminate the index value of columns and rows in a python dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to eliminate the column and the row which state the index of the values and replace the first value of my column by 'kw'.

Have tried .drop without success

```py
def main():

    df_old_m, df_new_m = open_file_with_data_m(file_old_m, file_new_m)
    #combine two dataframes together
    df = df_old_m.append(df_new_m)
    son=df["son"]
    gson=df["gson"]
    #add son
    df_old_m = df["seeds"].append(son)
    #add gson
    df_old_m = df_old_m.append(gson)
    #deleted repeated values
    df_old_m = df_old_m.drop_duplicates()

    #add kw as the header of the list
    df_old_m.loc[-1] = 'kw'  # adding a row
    df_old_m.index = df_old_m.index + 1  # shifting index
    df_old_m.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

This gives me [.xlsx output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1RJg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `kw` is the column you want to be your new index, you can do this:

`df.set_index('kw', inplace=True)`